# HttpClient - How to request non-JSON data

Tags: angular, typescript

### SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

I want to download excel through api ..i tried this method but unfortunately im getting this error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:5002/vendor.js:28768:51)

my Code here

```
getSalesARExcel(attach: string): Observable<any>{
    const obj={
        "AttachmentId":attach
    }
    return this.http.post(baseUrl + 'api/report/aging/receivables/summary/download/xlsx', obj ,{
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Authorization":'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, Methods, Content-Type',
            'responseType': 'ResponseContentType.Blob'
        })
    })
}

this.excel.getSalesARExcel(value.attach).subscribe(res => {
    console.log("excel", res)
    this.downloadExcelFile(res);
})

downloadExcelFile(data: any){
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
    var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: Obviously, the response data is not JSON. Could you please show what the server response is? Your localhost is not accessible over the Internet.

Comment: my response data is excel : application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: And what is the code of your `http.post` method?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the CORS headers and make `responseType` an option, not a header:

```
getSalesARExcel(attach: string): Observable<any>{
    const obj={
        "AttachmentId":attach
    }
    return this.http.post(url, obj ,{
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Authorization":'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
            ̶'̶A̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶-̶C̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶-̶A̶l̶l̶o̶w̶-̶O̶r̶i̶g̶i̶n̶'̶:̶'̶*̶'̶,̶
            ̶'̶A̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶-̶C̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶-̶A̶l̶l̶o̶w̶-̶H̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶'̶:̶'̶O̶r̶i̶g̶i̶n̶,̶ ̶M̶e̶t̶h̶o̶d̶s̶,̶ ̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶-̶T̶y̶p̶e̶'̶,̶
            ̶'̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶T̶y̶p̶e̶'̶:̶ ̶'̶R̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶T̶y̶p̶e̶.̶B̶l̶o̶b̶'̶
        }),
        'responseType': 'blob'
    })
}
```

CORS headers are response headers, not request headers.

The `responseType` is an XHR option, not a header.

For more information, see

- [Angular Developer Guide - httpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)
- [Angular API Reference - httpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)
- [Angular Developer Guide - Requesting non-JSON data](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)
- [Angular API Reference - http.post](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

Comment: For the visual studio code users: this solution might give you an error, ignore it and update your TSLint. This solution works fine but somehow older versions of TSLint will give you an error whilst applying this solution.