# Angular SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to download an xls file with my angular application, this has worked before angular 8 and suddenly doesn't work anymore. Here is what I have so far:

```
  export(selectedUsers: any) {
    this.getReport(selectedUsers).subscribe(data => this.downloadFile(data));
  }

  private getReport(selectedUsers: number[]): Observable<Blob> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({'content-type' : 'application/json',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                                responseType : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
    return this.http.post<Blob>(this.globals.api + 'persoon/export', selectedUsers, {headers, 'blob'});
  }

  private downloadFile(data: Blob) {
    console.log('downloading...');
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }
```

In the angular documentation it mentioned something like `HttpEvent<Blob>`, I also tried this but it didn't work. I tried out this similar question: [HttpClient - How to request non-JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492337/httpclient-how-to-request-non-json-data) But the solution did not work either since it basically said that it didn't accept the responseType in the given position.

I also checked the response headers of my request, the content-type is also `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Here are my imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Mail } from './models/mail';
import { Klant } from './models/klant';
import { GlobalsService } from './globals.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction and help me solve this issue?

**My console error**
[image: The console error]
**NOTE**

I got another issue after applying the accepted solution:

```
the expected type comes from property 'responseType' which is declared here on type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'
```

For this you should go here: [Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771603/types-of-property-responsetype-are-incompatible)

Comment: Could you try providing the header `{ responseType: 'text' }` ? I'm not sure this will work, but I'm not sure it won't either

Comment: @Maryannah same error, tried it with the headers and type of downloadFile and both separately .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the post you referenced. The `responseType: 'blob'` is not an header but an option in the request. so your request should look like:

```
  private getReport(selectedUsers: number[]): Observable<Blob> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'content-type' : 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    });
    return this.http.post<Blob>(this.globals.api + 'persoon/export', selectedUsers, {headers, ResponseType: 'blob'});
  }
```

Comment: Wait what, I just ignored the error visual studio code gave me and it works, this is awkward...

Comment: I also had to remove <Blob> because I got another exception that lead me to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771603/types-of-property-responsetype-are-incompatible

Comment: No overload matches this call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track with moving `responseType`, as it is an option for the request (i.e., to be interpreted by `HttpClient`), not a header (to be interpreted by the server receiving the request).

```
  private getReport(selectedUsers: number[]): Observable<Blob> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({'content-type' : 'application/json',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
                               );
        const options = {
            headers: headers,
            responseType: 'blob'
            };
    return this.http.post<Blob>(this.globals.api + 'persoon/export', selectedUsers, options);
  }
```